# Iterating through list elements - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following list:

```
<ul class="my-list">
   <li>
     <ul>
      <li>Now</li> 
      <li><img src="image.png"/></li> //change this
      <li>25˚</li> //change this
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     <ul>
      <li>12 AM</li>
      <li><img src="image.png"/></li>
      <li>30˚</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to iterate through this list and change the 'li' elements inside the second 'ul' (the img src, hour etc).

I've made the following jQuery code:

```
        if($(this).attr('class')=='my-list'){
            $("li").each(function(){
                $("ul").each(function(){
                    $("li:eq(0)").html("Test");
                    $("li:eq(1)").html("test2");
                    $("li:eq(2)").html("test3");
                });
            });
        }
```

I'm trying to use the same code for the code list (this is just a part of it), but my jQuery code is not working and I can't figure out why.
Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: what is `this`? Show full context of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate li element with descendant of current ul that matched and target only second li :

```
if ($(this).attr('class') == 'my-list') {
    // this only target second element of 'li'
    $(this).children().eq(1).each(function () {
       // then find ul element
        $(this).find('ul').each(function () {
            // change the content by using context
            $("li:eq(0)", this).html("Test");
            $("li:eq(1)", this).html("test2");
            $("li:eq(2)",this).html("test3");
        });
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/xo8vr7fv/) - *click on the list to see the changes*

Comment: It worked, thank you! Now I see where I was getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are iterating through matched elements, you are not using them to narrow down their children nodes. Try this instead

```
$('.my-list ul').each(function(index, elem){
    var innerList = $(elem).children('li');
    innerList.eq(0).html('Test')
    innerList.eq(1).html('Test2')
    innerList.eq(2).html('Test3')
});
```